# Java help regarding looping (do loops)

Tags: java, loops, do-loops

I'm trying to make a very basic game where you guess a number between 1-1000 using a do loop.  Everything works, except when I finally make the correct guess, I am still prompted to make another guess, and when I enter the same correct guess again, the program terminates like it's suppose to.

Why do I have to make that extra guess to finally get my program to work? Am I looping around an extra time? Also, if I make a correct guess (the compiler will say I am correct then still prompt me), then a wrong guess (the compiler will tell me I'm wrong), then the correct guess again, the program will only terminate after I make the correct guess a second time.

The second do loop at the bottom is what I put in my main method.  Everything above is in a method I wrote called play.

```
public static boolean play()
{

    boolean c;
    int n = 0;

    do {
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number between 1-1000");
        n = Integer.parseInt(input);

        if (n == guess)
        {
            System.out.println("Correct");
            c = true;
        }
        else if (n < guess)
        {
            System.out.println("Not Right");
            c = false;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Not Right");
            c = false;
        }

        guess++;

    } while (c == false);

    return c;

}
```

In main method:

```
    do {
        game1.play();
    } while (game1.play() != true);
```

Comment: where is the value of guess?

Comment: When you call `game1.play()` in the while, it is executed again.  Stick the value into a variable like you did in the previous do-while loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This loop runs the play method twice in each iteration of the loop :

```
do {
    game1.play(); // first call
} while (game1.play()!=true); // second call
```

You are not testing the value returned by the first call, so even if it returns true, you would still call `game1.play()` again, which will display "Enter a number between 1-1000" again.

Replace it with:

```
boolean done = false;
do {
    done = game1.play();
} while (!done);
```

This would only call `play()` one time in each iteration of the loop.

That said, I'm not sure why you need the outer loop. 
You can just replace in with one call to `game1.play()`, since `game1.play()` will loop until the correct number is entered.